# Is "stick with reality" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage

Ok, let say you are running a restaurant. When making important decisions, you often subjectively give your own personal ideas without paying attention to the real needs in reality or in real world. For example, the trend of diet in real world is eat less fatty and salty food, but your restaurant's menu has many fatty and salty dishes.

So, in this case, can I say "*you do not stick with reality*"?

I searched "*stick with reality*" in Google and found many results but found no definition of that expression.

So, Is "*stick with reality*" idiomatic?

Comment: Not really idiomatic, but sorta understood.  "Keep it real" is the idiom.

Comment: can I use "be realistic"?

Answer (score 1):

The only way in which it's idiomatic is when you are making a comparison to fantasy or an alternative world. "I think I'll stick with reality!",  line in a movie when given the choice to go back in the Matrix, etc.

For your purposes try something like, You ignore trends; You're out of touch with reality; You're always trying to buck the trend (more deliberate), really you have lots of choices.